# beenHere always zero in /venues/search result

Tags: foursquare

When doing a /venues/search query while authenticated, in my app or in the explorer, the venues come back with the beenHere count equal to zero.

```
/venues/search?ll=37.77215646,-122.40612745&query=meexo&intent=match

beenHere: {
  count: 0
}
```

However if I do a /venues/ query for the same venues, they have the proper beenHere value.

```
/venues/4e76087d18506506ccad575b

beenHere: {
  count: 112
  marked: true
}
```

Is this a know issue or a bug? I can work around this by iterating over the venues and doing individual requests, but it seems that it would be better to return no value in the search results rather than an incorrect one.

Also, what is the "marked" property in the complete venue response? I don't see it mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venue).

Comment: That's definitely a bug. Thanks for the report, I've filed a ticket with the appropriate team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix for the herenow always 0 issue will be rolled out today or tomorrow for versioned requests 20120609 or later.

Comment: Can you also comment on what the "marked: true" field is about? I can't find it in the docs.